# Call extended inner class of another class?

Tags: java, android, oop

In order to implement a watchface for Android wear, I am using `CanvasWatchFaceService`. This uses an `Engine` that makes changes on the canvas. A sample code is shown below:

```
public class WatchFace extends CanvasWatchFaceService {

    @Override
    public MyEngine onCreateEngine() {
        return new MyEngine();
    }

    private class MyEngine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine { ... }
    // The above line is basically:
    // private class MyEngine extends WatchFace.Engine { ... }
}
```

Suppose I want to have multiple `CanvasWatchFaceService` classes that use only one `Engine`. This is because the code within `Engine` is reusable for my purpose.

How would this be possible? I can't seem to be able to take out `MyEngine` on its own since an enclosing instance of type `CanvasWatchFaceService` must be in scope. For the same reason, also cannot make it static.

What would be the best way to approach this problem?

----------------------------UPDATE:---------------------------
Here's what I have done so far that does not give me a syntax error:

```
 public class WatchFace2 extends CanvasWatchFaceService {

    @Override
    public WatchFace.MyEngine onCreateEngine() {
        return new WatchFace(WatchFace2.this).onCreateEngine();
    }

}
```

, and added a contructor for `WatchFace` that takes in the given `CanvasWatchFaceService` as context, necessary for the inside working of `MyEngine`.

This runs fine but there are semantic errors regarding `getPackageName()`. Error does not show break at any line from my code.

Comment: I think what I mean is if I have another `public class WatchFace2 extends CanvasWatchFaceService`, I want it to return an instance of the above `MyEngine` from its `onCreateEngine()` method too.

Comment: I have tried that: called new WatchFace(Watchface2.this).onCreateMethod() from another class Watchface2. I get errors from within the MyEngine class regarding get package name. Tried sending an instance of WathFace2 as a constructor too, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class WatchFace extends CanvasWatchFaceService {

    @Override
    public MyEngine onCreateEngine() {
        return new MyEngine();
    }

    private class MyEngine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine { ... }
    // The above line is basically:
    // private class MyEngine extends WatchFace.Engine { ... }
}
```

then extend `WatchFace`

```
public class WatchFace1 extends WatchFace{ 
}

public class WatchFace2 extends WatchFace{
}
```

Comment: WatchFace.this cannot be referenced form a static context.

Comment: the whole point of the 'private' keyword is that it's not visible from other classes

Comment: unless I make MyEngine() static, I cant reference it directly. But if I make it static, it wont have an enclosing type of CanvasWatchFaceService

Comment: also, how can i set some data before onCreateEngine is called?

Comment: For each WatchFacex , if I have say different background colors, how would I transmit that information for MyEngine to process?

Comment: add method myEngine.process(Color color). and add a method public void process(Color color){myEngine.process(color)} to WatchFace

Comment: please ask a different question if you have further questions. this comment chain is getting too long